# As a python package maintainer, how can I determine lowest working requirements

Tags: python, dependencies, backwards-compatibility, python-packaging, developer-tools

While it is possible to simply use `pip freeze` to get the current environment, it is not suitable to require an environment as bleeding edge as what I am used too.
Moreover, some developer tooling are only available on recent version of packages (think type annotations), but not needed for users.
My target users may want to use my package on slowly upgrading machines, and I want to get my requirements as low as possible.
For example, I cannot require better than Python 3.6 (and even then I think some users may be unable to use the package).
Similarly, I want to avoid requiring the last Numpy or Matplotlib versions.

**Is there a (semi-)automatic way of determining the oldest compatible version of each dependency?**

Alternatively, I can manually try to build a conda environment with old packages, but I would have to try pretty randomly.
Unfortunately, I inherited a medium-sized codebase (~10KLoC) with no automated test yet (I plan on making some, but it takes some time, and it sadly cannot be my priority).
The requirements were not properly defined either so that I don't know what it has been run with two years ago.

Comment: An application should `pip freeze` its current requirements and require to run with exactly that. But a library should be less strict, and allow for the lowest demominator for requirements, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **semantic versionning** is not always honored (and because it may be difficult from a developper standpoint to determine what is a minor or major change exactly for each possible user), and because only a human can parse release notes to understand what has changed, there is no simple solution.

My technical approach would be to create a virtual environment with a known working combination of Python and libraries versions. From there, downgrade one version by one version, one lib at a time, verifying that it still works fine (may be difficult if it is manual and/or long to check).

My social solution would be to timebox the technical approach to take no more than a few hours. Then settle for what you have reached. Indicate in the README that lib requirements may be overblown and that help is welcome.

Without fast automated tests in which you are confident, there is no way to automate the exploration of the N-space (each library is a dimension) to find a some minimums.

Comment: I guess the time-based approach is a nice workaround. I was thinking, given the fantastic introspection powers of python, there may be some way to analyse what is actually used in the package and see in which version of dependencies it is present. Of course, if a function changed its interface, it makes the approach fragile. Type annotations may make this kind of approach more efficient in the future. Maybe I just have to write such a tool.

Comment: @WIP Python comes with the [ast library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) if you want to try to parse the code also. While this or your suggestions could work, finding semantic changes is **incredibly** difficult, notably so for a language dynamic as Python. I would not try the introspection way on my work hours, from my point of view it would be pointless. But I may be wrong a some PyGuru could come and hand you a very very clever solution. But prefer the known way : put some tests, and bisect library by library, version by version.

Comment: I am sure it would be a difficult task and I would indeed not try on my work hours. It would probably take more time to write such a tool than to first write my test suite and then bisect the versions. Still, it would be a useful tool and I may look into it in my free time.